# Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in

Tags: php, mysql

Here is a code which give the error.
The code is below.

```
$search = ("SELECT `patData` FROM `reportData` WHERE id = 2")
            or die (mysql_error());

echo mysql_result($search,1);
```

In this code `$search` Query is work well.

Comment: Share your full code please !

Comment: ... What query? You don't perform one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT `patData` FROM `reportData` WHERE id = 2");

if (!$search) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}
echo mysql_result($search, 0);
```

The problem is that mysql_query() is may be returning a **Boolean** instead of a result resource. There are two reasons this can happen:

1. You performed query that returns success/fail instead of a result set.
2. Your query failed.

**Notes :**

1. Don't write code that uses the mysql_* functions. They are deprecated and will eventually be removed from PHP.
2. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: @Axeem Put on your reading glasses and take a close look at `mysql_query`.

Comment: No, It can't return **Bollean** value. And query is not failed.

Comment: @Axeem,Please put mysql_result($search, 0); at your end & try it.I have also edited my answer.Let me know if you still have any issues.

Comment: Problem is that I can't pass the query in `mysql_query` function. Now its work well.

Comment: @Axeem,Yes that's why I have added mysql_query in my answer.Hope My answer helps to resolve your issue.